# My Codename One form is loading all the parts, then scrolling off the screen to the left, and showing a blank screen in the Simulator

Tags: codenameone

I have added a second form to my app, and it scrolls off the screen to the left in the simulator, leaving a blank form on the screen. In the attached code my call from the splash screen menu is shown first, then my class. I do not see what is flushing my form, as Shai identified what was probably happening with my first form, and I do not know what I did to stop the first form from scrolling off. Does anyone see my error? Thanks.

```
// Call on Splash Screen
    public boolean openField2() throws IOException {
        Form mbd = new MoveByDrag();
        mbd.show();
       return false;
    }
// New Form
package com.kcconsulting.soccersession.ui;

import com.codename1.components.ScaleImageLabel;
import com.codename1.ui.*;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.*;
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import static com.codename1.ui.CN.getCurrentForm;
import static com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS;
import com.codename1.ui.table.TableLayout;

public class MoveByDrag extends Form {
    Form playfield = new Form();
    Container controls = new Container();
    Container field = new Container();
    Image img30;
    public MoveByDrag() throws IOException {
        TableLayout t2 = new TableLayout(2, 1);
        playfield.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToSideMenu(" Design by Coordinates",
                FontImage.MATERIAL_CHECK, 4, e -> {
                // Rebuild Menu after stopping Scroll to blank screen
                });
        playfield.setLayout(t2);
        field.getAllStyles().setBgImage(Image.createImage("/BlankField.jpg"));
        playfield.add(t2.createConstraint().heightPercentage(10).widthPercentage(100), controls);
        playfield.add(t2.createConstraint().heightPercentage(90).widthPercentage(100), field);
        playfield.show();
    }
    //Build Drag and Drop
/*
    public void drop(Component dragged, int x, int y) {
        int i = playfield.getComponentIndex(dragged);
        if(i > -1) {
            Component dest = playfield.getComponentAt(x, y);
            if(dest != dragged) {
                int destIndex = playfield.getComponentIndex(dest);
                if(destIndex > -1 && destIndex != i) {
 //                   playfield.setComponentIndex(dragged,destIndex);
                }
            }
            playfield.animateLayout(400);
        } else {
            Container oldParent = dragged.getParent();
            if(oldParent != null) {
                oldParent.removeComponent(dragged);
            }
            Component pos = playfield.getComponentAt(x, y);
            i = playfield.getComponentIndex(pos);
            if(i > -1) {
                playfield.addComponent(i, dragged);
            } else {
                playfield.addComponent(dragged);
            }
            playfield.getComponentForm().animateHierarchy(400);
        }
    }
*/

}
```

Comment: Shai, Thanks for the response. I ran with the blue background you did, and added my field background, and took videos of both. How can I get the videos to you? Could it be something that needs to be rebuilt in IntelliJ?

Comment: Simplest method is to upload to youtube as unlisted video and include the links here. Also explain the problem in case it isn't obvious from the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this variation of your code:

```
TableLayout t2 = new TableLayout(2, 1);
Form playfield = new Form(t2);
Container controls = new Container();
Container field = new Container();
field.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xff);
field.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(0xff);
playfield.add(t2.createConstraint().heightPercentage(10).widthPercentage(100), controls);
playfield.add(t2.createConstraint().heightPercentage(90).widthPercentage(100), field);
playfield.show();
```

It didn't scroll to the side or have any problem I could see. It should be functionally identical. Can you provide screenshots or a video illustrating what you're seeing?

[image: Screenshot of above code]

Comment: Shai asked me to post a video of the issue I am having. The link to the video is https://youtu.be/33YkrhyhWcQ . One thing that I thought of, is it possible that I am having issues based on my .jar having artifacts from my previous attempted changes? I am wondering if since I only have 3 classes built, should I start with a fresh base build and refactor my classes, and move my images into the theme? Thanks to everyone for their ideas. Thanks Shai.

Comment: This isn't due to the form. I'm guessing this is a bug with your menu code that seems to have two events bound to it. The first shows the form correctly. The second shows a blank form. How do you show the form? Is there any code other than `new MoveByDrag()`? That might be the issue.

Comment: My call is new MovebyDrag() entered above. The Menu call is:                                              try {
                        openField2();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                    }        .....I will work with the code and clean up everything I can. Thanks.

Comment: What does `openField2()` do?

Comment: That is the call in the menu for the method I included on top of the code entry above, described as Call on Splash Screen. Happy New Year, everyone.

Comment: `MoveByDrag` inherits `Form` that's one form. In it you have another `Form` `playfield`. The constructor invokes `playfield.show()` which shows the first `Form` with your content. Then you invoke `show()` on the `Form` you inherit which is blank. Remove the `exends Form` and redundant `show()` call.

Comment: Thanks, Shai. I cleaned my call and removed the extends Form from the class and it is working now. Thank you for continuing to pick at the problem.